# vHost redirect not working at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, vhosts

Goal: Redirecting every request to index.php except the files and folders (and their content) listed in the RewriteCond.

A friend did set up the server with me, but hadn't any time to fix this bug yet. The page automatically ends up at HTTPS.

When using this as 000-default.conf (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf), the page just doesn't redirect to index.php. For example: Accessing www.page.com/uploads/38 works, although it should redirect to www.page.com/index.php. That's quite annoying as I'm emulating a filesystem and don't want to allow access to the files, at least not that way.

a2ensite 000-default.conf: Site 000-default.conf is already enabled
a2enmod rewrite: Module rewrite already enabled

This is my 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin root@page.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default
  ServerName www.page.com
  ServerAlias page.com
  RewriteEngine On
  <Location />
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|css|fonts|gfx|js|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
  </Location>
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin root@page.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default
  ServerName www.page.com
  ServerAlias page.com
  RewriteEngine On
  <Location />
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|css|fonts|gfx|js|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
  </Location>
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/page.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/page.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/comodo-ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

When looking at default_error.log, I often find stuff like this:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

And also:

```
RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `page.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable starts with a `/`, your regex doesn't so that condition will always be true, including when the URI gets rewritten to `/index.php`, this is causing the loop.

Replace the block with:

```
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|fonts|gfx|js|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Additionally, I'm guessing you've bought a certificate for the name "page.com", **not** "www.page.com", which means when you go to "www.page.com" and the browser sees a certificate for "page.com", it'll throw an exception. You need a cert for "www.page.com" (and optionally with "page.com" as an alternate name)/.

---

EDIT

Hmm, this didn't work for me either inside the `<Location />` container. But this worked outside of the container by itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|fonts|gfx|js|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php [L,R]
```

Comment: I used $1 now (we already did that before, then tested %{REQUEST_URI} and restarted Apache. Still the same problem, I'm still able to access page.com/uploads/38 (I end up at https://www.page.com/uploads/38).

Comment: @Lutan Oh, you want to literally redirect the browser? Then you need to use the `R` flag in the square brackets: `[L,R]` or `[L,R=301]` for a permanent redirect.

Comment: I tested [L,R] and [L,R=301] and restarted apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart), still not working...

Comment: I changed it to your edit, and now it redirects. One question left: Before I did a serverreset, I used emulated paths && REQUEST_URI (page.com/Lutan/test/stuff.txt outputs /Lutan/test/stuff.txt as REQUEST_URI while running index.php) to show specific data. It didn't change the url either. Is there an easy way (or like, any way at all) to do this?

Comment: @Lutan a redirect is an entirely new request, therefore whatever the browser originally requested is lost.

Comment: Okay, then I was mistaken, sorry. How do I keep the REQUEST_URI and url? I only want to process the request with my index.php except it's one of the specified files or folders.

Comment: @Lutan the REQUEST_URI is the URL, if you want to keep them, remove the R flag

Comment: I had to add a / in front of the index.php as well as in front of each folder and file I wanted to exclude, it now works as wanted. Thanks again.